# How to rank elements in a table and create variables in Python

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

If we had nominal ratings (as shown in the table) given by players A, B and C for players a, b and c (i.e., player A rates player a-8, player b-6 and player c-9), is there a way in Python to rank each player's choices and create variables that can be used later on?

```
╔════════╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ Player ║ a ║ b ║ c ║
╠════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║   A    ║ 8 ║ 6 ║ 9 ║
║   B    ║ 5 ║ 7 ║ 9 ║
║   C    ║ 7 ║ 8 ║ 6 ║
╚════════╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

So in this case, I'd like a function that would sort A's preferences as c, a, b then create 3 variables to reference later in the code;

```
A_Preference_1 = c
A_Preference_2 = a
A_Preference_3 = b
```

Sorry if this seems vague but any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's better to avoid creating new variables from names. Can you use lists as dictionary values instead? e.g. `player_prefs = {'A': ['c', 'a', 'b'], 'B': ['c', 'b', 'a']....}` and so on

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary of dictionaries, then you have all necessary information together.

```
from operator import itemgetter


ratings = {
    'A': {'a': 8, 'b': 6, 'c': 9},
    'B': {'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'c': 9},
    'C': {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 6},
    }

for player, rating in ratings.items():
    # Now you can find the max, sort the ratings, etc..
    favorite = max(rating.items(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
    # Use str.format() if your Python version is < 3.6.
    print(f"{player}'s favorite is {favorite}.")
    sorted_ratings = sorted(rating.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
    print(player, sorted_ratings)
```

Output:

```
A's favorite is c.
A [('b', 6), ('a', 8), ('c', 9)]
B's favorite is c.
B [('a', 5), ('b', 7), ('c', 9)]
C's favorite is b.
C [('c', 6), ('a', 7), ('b', 8)]
```